# Lucene - autocomplete using facet labels?

Tags: java, autocomplete, lucene, faceted-search

I have a Lucene (6.4.2) index with about 2-5M documents, and each document has about 10 facets (for example 'author', 'publisher', etc).

I have a search bar on top of my application, and would like to implement autocomplete with these facets. For example, when the user enters `Jo` I would like the options to be:

```
'John Doe - Author'
'Jonatan Driver - Publisher'
'Joan Deville - Author'
...
```

My facets are structured using the `FacetFields` and Lucene Taxonomy, like this:

```
'Author / John Doe'
'Author / Joan Deville'
...
```

Are there built-in options to create such an autocomplete? Or do I have to build it myself?

I prefer not to do a search on all the documents and retrieve facets for those, because that is not very fast.